# How to 'bridge' the newly bonded NIC?

Tags: bridge, bonding

I bonded `eth0`, `eth1`, `eth2` and `eth3` of my server to create a single `bond0` interface using the `ifenslave` package. Now I wish to create multiple Virtual machines on this server in order to set-up a cluster. These VMs require to have a 'bridged' network connection.

However, the Virtual machine software I am using (http://virt-manager.org/) says that `bond0` is not bridged.

How do I make it bridged?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You'll need the package `bridge-utils` to set up bridging.

I found an example configuration file (found [here](http://chienpo.blogspot.com/2010/06/bridging-and-bonding-with-ubuntu-server.html)):

```
# /etc/network/interfaces
auto lo
iface lo inet loopback

# The bonded network interface
auto bond0
iface bond0 inet manual
    bond-slaves none
    bond-mode   802.3ad
    bond-miimon 100

# Enslave all the physical interfaces
auto eth0
iface eth0 inet manual
    bond-master bond0

auto eth1
iface eth1 inet manual
    bond-master bond0

auto eth2
iface eth2 inet manual
    bond-master bond0

auto eth3
iface eth3 inet manual
    bond-master bond0

# Configure the bridging interface
auto br0
iface br0 inet static
    address 10.0.0.10
    netmask 255.255.255.0
    gateway 10.0.0.1
    bridge-ports  bond0
    bridge-fd     9
    bridge-hello  2
    bridge-maxage 12
    bridge-stp    off
```

Simply modify the address/netmask to your needs and it should work nicely.

Answer (score 1):

You may want to consider not using bridged bonds, KVM admit theres a bug, better to add the two physical interfaces to the VM and bond them inside the VM.

Source: http://www.linux-kvm.org/page/HOWTO_BONDING#Problem_with_Bridge_.2B_Bonding